# Javascript injection has no effect

Tags: javascript, html, swift, dom, swift3

There is a strange problem: i can run some scripts on pages, but another scripts doesn't work. Please help me to understand why. 
Here is the example. I got a HTML element by `webView(evalueteJavaScript:)`, it's a simple link to logout, and i want to click it. But when script runs - nothing happens. BTW, same script successfully does logout when i paste it to the console in regular browsers (Like Safari & Chrome)

Also i got similar problems with another websites but different elements. 
Like input textFields which cant save data pasted into it by the script (even through console). Seems like they are waiting for some user interaction, or smth like that. Or i'm doing it wrong…

HTML

```
<a href="#" title="logout" class="exit">logout</a>
```

Swift 3

```
func logOut() {

    webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.querySelector('#header > div > a.exit').click()", completionHandler: { (result, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print("Logout error - \(error?.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            print("Logout ok! \(result)")
        }
    })

    self.webView.reloadFromOrigin()   
}
```